# Question about definition of a group/Unit element of a group

Tags: group-theory

So I have this question:

> Show that $\mathbb{Z}$ with the operation
>   $$m * n = m + (-1)^m n$$
>   is a group. What is the unit element of this group? What is the inverse of $n$? Find all elements of order two (recall that an element $a$ of a multiplicatively written group $G$ is of order two, if $a \neq 1$ and $a^2 = a \cdot a = 1$).

On my assignment, it's the last question and I've been fine up until now but I have absolutely no idea for this question, so it would be great if somebody could help me out

Comment: Can you either (a) write out the question using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (basically put dollar signs $ around everything), or (b) fix the picture. Currently it is just a link... (EDIT: I notice people have edited your other questions to make your pictures text, and now someone has edited this one. This comes across as laziness on your part...)

Comment: Well, do you have any idea what a group is? There are a bunch of rules to check, and your first step is trying to check them. (Having absolutely no idea is a *really* bad thing in a case like this, and I rather doubt that's the truth.)

Comment: By "unit element of the group", they probably mean the identity. Notice that $m*0 = m + (-1)^m0 = m = 0 + (-1)^0m = 0*m$.

Comment: Hi! Just a heads up, generally speaking, it's not considered good form to link to pictures of questions on this site, for various reasons. I've edited your post so that the question appears in the text. If you want to see how I did it, you can click the link above my name, where it say's I've edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

**hint:** an identity element is one that "does nothing" in the sense that you want

$$e*n=e+(-1)^en=n=n+(-1)^ne=n*e.$$

This is just an expanded way of writing $n*e=n=e*n$. Can you find some integer $e$ that satisfies this property?